# Can I install and run Memgraph on Amazon Linux?

Tags: memgraphdb

I would like to run Memgraph on Amazon Linux. How can I install it? Are there prebuild packages specific for Amazon Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Amazon Linux you would probably need a working build for Fedora. Installation instructions can be found at https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/install-memgraph-from-rpm, and the RPM package can be dowloaded from https://memgraph.com/download/.

The install procedure is rather easy:

1. Install the package: `sudo yum --nogpgcheck localinstall /path-to/memgraph-<version>.rpm`
2. Run the service: `systemctl start memgraph`

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Memgraph package for Linux on the [Memgraph download page](https://memgraph.com/download). At the moment Memgraph offers installation packets for the following Linux distributions:

- CentOS 7
- CentOS 9
- Fedora 36
- Debian 10
- Debian 11
- Debian 11 (ARM64/AArch64)
- Ubuntu 18.04
- Ubuntu 20.04
- Ubuntu 22.04

On top of that, you can install Memgraph as [Docker on Linux](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/install-memgraph-db-on-linux-docker).

Also, if you want, you can deploy Memgraph using [Docker](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/reference-guide/deployment/docker) or [Kubernetes](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/reference-guide/deployment/kubernetes).

Amazon Linux is not listed and supported at the moment. Since it [supports RPM packages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-software.html), packages for CentOS could work but I didn't test it.